# Expand CollapsingToolbarLayout in the middle of Scroll when minimum height is set to ToolBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using the following code to expand/collapse the toolbar. Everything is working fine but I want to expand the toolbar to it's height when user do the scroll down.

Currently it is expanding only when recyclerview reaches to the top. I want to expand the tool bar even if recyclerview is just scrolled down.

Is it possible to expand/collapse the toolbar just by dragging up/down the imageview ?

I tried enterAlways and other flags but it is not maintaining the minimum height set to toolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/apbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Why _Toolbar_ height _150dp_. It should be _56dp_

Comment: @piyush There is no 'should be'. He wants to expand the toolbar

Comment: @Piyush I don't want to hide the entire image. So, I made it as 150dp